# how to merge fragmented packets comming from same source?

Tags: wireshark, packet, tcpdump, tshark

I have fragmented packets coming from multiple sources stored in a `*.pcap` file. I need to merge all these payloads coming from the same source and extract the payloads in a file.

I need to do the above task using `tcpdump` or `tshark` commands.

Please let me know if I have missed something or if you need more clarification.

Comment: Cool.  So what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

With [pdml2flow](https://github.com/Enteee/pdml2flow) ([pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pdml2flow/)) you can merge/aggregate frames based on any fields extracted by tshark / wireshark and print them as JSON, XML or any other format. You can also easily [create a new plugin](https://github.com/Enteee/pdml2flow#create-a-new-plugin) which extracts, rearranges and saves the payload for your use-case.

For example if you'd like to aggregate all frames with the same source and destination mac and print them as JSON you could do:

```
tshark -i interface -Tpdml | pdml2flow -f eth.src -f eth.dst +json
```

This might help if you can find a set of fields based on which you would like to merge/aggregate.

*Disclosure*: I am the author of [pdml2flow](https://pypi.org/project/pdml2flow/).